# how can i print this java script code in google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have used `console.log()` to print this code but it shows nothing in the browser. What is the problem? Is there any other ways to print it without using `console.log()`? I am using Google Chrome as a browser.

```js
var database = [{
  username: "omar",
  password: "secret"
}];

var newsFeed = [{
    username: "Amer",
    timeline: "i hate studying"
  },
  {
    username: "Khalid",
    timeline: "i'm hungry "
  }
];

var userName = prompt("what is your username?");
var passWord = prompt(" what is your password?");

function signIn(user, pass) {
  if (user === database[0].username && pass === database[0].password) {
    console.log(newsFeed);

  } else
    alert("sorry your username or password is not correct!");
}

signIn(userName, passWord);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, I just ran it and it logged to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var database = [{
  username: "omar",
  password: "secret"
}];

var newsFeed = [
  {
    username: "Amer",
    timeline: "i hate studying"
  },
  {
    username: "Khalid",
    timeline: "i'm hungry "
  }
];

var userName = prompt("what is your username?");
var passWord = prompt(" what is your password?");

function signIn(user, pass) {
  if (user === database[0].username && pass === database[0].password) {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(newsFeed, null, '  ')}</pre>`;

  } else
    alert("sorry your username or password is not correct!");
}

signIn(userName, passWord);
```